# Isomorphism between global sections of normal sheaf and $\mathrm{Ext}^1_X(i_*\mathcal{O}_Z, i_*\mathcal{O}_Z)$

Tags: algebraic-geometry

Let $X$ be an n–dimensional compact algebraic manifold, $i \colon Z \to X$
a closed submanifold, and let $\mathcal{N}_{Z|X}$ denote the normal sheaf. I have trouble understanding the isomorphism
$$
H^0(Z,\mathcal{N}_{Z|X}) \xrightarrow{\cong} \mathrm{Ext}^1_X(i_*\mathcal{O}_Z, i_*\mathcal{O}_Z)
$$
stated in the paper https://arxiv.org/pdf/math/9912245.pdf in the statement of Proposition 8.7.
I think I understand how the map is defined, i.e., by applying the functor $\operatorname{Hom}_X(-, i_*\mathcal{O}_Z)$ to the short exact sequence
$$ 0 \to \mathcal{I} \to \mathcal{O}_X \to i_* \mathcal{O}_Z \to 0$$ and considering the associated long exact sequence.

I believe the map so obtained is injective,
however I don't understand how to prove it is surjective.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is not surjective in general. Indeed, the associated long exact sequence looks like
$$
0 \to 
H^0(Z,\mathcal{N}_{Z/X}) \to 
\mathrm{Ext}^1(i_*\mathcal{O}_Z,i_*\mathcal{O}_Z) \to H^1(Z,\mathcal{O}_Z) \to 
\mathrm{Ext}^1(\mathcal{I}_Z,i_*\mathcal{O}_Z) \to \dots
$$
Now assume, for instance, $Z$ is a plane cubic curve. Then $\mathcal{I}_Z \cong \mathcal{O}(-3)$, hence
$$
\mathrm{Ext}^1(\mathcal{I}_Z,i_*\mathcal{O}_Z) \cong H^1(Z,\mathcal{O}_Z(3)) = 0,
$$
while $H^1(Z,\mathcal{O}_Z) \ne 0$.